# Converting character column to Date in r

Tags: r, date, datetime-format

consider I have a data like:

```
Month-Year  Frequency

Apr-1997        33

Apr-1998        45

Apr-1999    31

Apr-2000    41

Apr-2001    34

Apr-2002    45
```

It contains frequencies for various months of the various years.
When I read above file using read.csv keeping stringsAsFactor=FALSE.
For Month-Year column I get character.

I am not getting how to convert this column to Date format in R.
When I am using as.Date it makes the entire column NA.

Comment: Dates need days, which you have not provided. Here is a possible method: `as.Date(paste0("Apr-1997", "-1"), "%b-%Y-%d")`.

Comment: @lmo, But my data consist of only months-year.

Comment: R needs a day. For the example I provided, I pasted on the first day of the month. You can replace "Apr-1997" with `dat$mont.year` or whatever data.frame variable name combination you have.

Comment: Following up on Imo's comments, if we didn't have a day, how would R know how add 1 week to `Apr-1997` for example? Unless I'm completely missing something, if you want it as a date object I believe you are required to put a day.

Comment: @lmo, Your code makes the format as "1997-04-01". Which I dont want. I actually want to plot the Month-Year, but for that I need Month-Year to be in Date format.

Comment: How are you planning on doing your plots? If you are using `ggplot` for your plotting, you can always change the formatting of the labels so that it is year - month

Comment: @MikeH., the above data is for the span of 18 years. the frequencies are aggregated for 18 years monthwise. I want to make a beautiful timeseries plot out of it